# Terraform postgres provider not recognize Azure Postgresql database version

Tags: azure, postgresql, terraform

I would create a postgresql database in azure and after it I would connect with the postgresql provider

Here is how I create the database

```
resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "qumulateserver" {
name                = "${var.database_server_name}"
location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.qumulateterraform.location}"  
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.qumulateterraform.name}"

sku {
name = "PGSQLB50"
capacity = 50
tier = "Basic"
}

administrator_login = "admin"
administrator_login_password = "password"
version = "9.5"
storage_mb = "51200"
ssl_enforcement = "Enabled"
}
```

Here how I would connect

```
provider "postgresql" {
alias = "pgconnect"
host = "${var.database_server_name}${var.postgres_fqdn}"
port = 5432
database = "${var.database_name}"
username = "${azurerm_postgresql_server.qumulateserver.administrator_login}@${var.database_server_name}${var.postgres_fqdn}"
password = "${azurerm_postgresql_server.qumulateserver.administrator_login_password}"
expected_version = "9.5.0"
}
```

So the probelm is with the versions. I get the following error
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

```
* provider.postgresql.pgconnect: Error initializing PostgreSQL client: error detecting capabilities: error parsing version: Invalid character(s) found in patch number "9,"
```

I tried to change the db versions to the same minor and patchset versions but doesn't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't use the latest version Terraform. I test in my lab, your tf file works for me. You could check the version with

```
 terraform -v
```

The following is my result.

```
[root@shui ~]# terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.3
+ provider.azurerm v1.1.0
+ provider.postgresql v0.1.1
```

If you don't use the latest version, I suggest you could download it from `https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.3/terraform_0.11.3_linux_amd64.zip?_ga=2.218208986.2119762406.1517451738-1224081222.1513669056`

The [tf](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/930dc3503758dafa96da4d5abc04a5c6/raw/0f41e95f627f756823d95411dffe23f38aac496e/sql.tf) file works for me. You could check it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt helps.
    Terraform v0.11.3
     + provider.azurerm v1.1.0
     + provider.postgresql v0.1.1

Comment: I tried to change the line endings and everything but I still have the same issue

Comment: I use this tf  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/930dc3503758dafa96da4d5abc04a5c6/raw/0f41e95f627f756823d95411dffe23f38aac496e/sql.tf  It works for me fine.

Comment: Do you check your host? Is this right?

Comment: Its working for me as well. Hmmm.

Comment: It seems you use wrong host `${var.database_name}.postgres.database.azure.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72530/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-gerga).

Comment: Apologies for my comment on such an old post, I could not find another way to reach @GergA ... I hope the DB password is not still the same as it was in 2018. The chat is not hidden from other users, and I was able to see the DB password posted in the chat in plaintext.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the exact same issue.

Seems like there is an issue with provider.postgresql v0.1.1.

Solved by using terraform-provider-postgresql_v0.1.0_x4.